# Move a graphviz node to north-west (top-left) corner

Tags: graphviz

I have the following code.

```
digraph topleft {
    graph [rankdir="LR", splines=ortho];
    node [shape=record];

    l1 [label="A\l|b\l"];
    l2 [label="C\l|d\l"];
    l3 [label="E\l|f\l"];
    l4 [label="G\l|h\l"];
    l5 [label="I\l|j\l"];
    l6 [label="K\l|l\l"];

    l1 -> l2 -> l6;
    l1 -> l3;
    l1 -> l4;
    l1 -> l5;
}
```

[image]

I want node A  to be moved to top-left corner and at the same time maintain the same rank status for nodes C, E, G and I.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may simply add a `group` attribute with the same value to `l1`, `l2` and `l6`:

```
digraph topleft {
    graph [rankdir="LR", splines=ortho];
    node [shape=record];

    l1 [label="A\l|b\l", group="a"];
    l2 [label="C\l|d\l", group="a"];
    l3 [label="E\l|f\l"];
    l4 [label="G\l|h\l"];
    l5 [label="I\l|j\l"];
    l6 [label="K\l|l\l", group="a"];

    l1 -> l2 -> l6;
    l1 -> l3;
    l1 -> l4;
    l1 -> l5;
}
```

Graphivz tries to render nodes belonging to the same group in a straight line, which moves `l1` up to the left upper corner.

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. The node is being moved to bottom-left with the code you provided. See the output [here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/461255/topleft.png).  Any idea how can this be improved?

Comment: I mixed up the nodes I put the attribute on, I edited my answer. BTW, your link asks me to provide an email for a download link...

Comment: Yes, it works for the above example. But it does not work for a larger diagram from which I extracted the scenario. I can post that one as update to my question, or if you permit me I can email it to you.